# Resize text in textbox along with div using jquery

Tags: jquery, text

I have an empty div with a textbox in it and If I write something in the textbox and If I enlarge the div by dragging to its corner the text inside the textbox should increase with the textbox.

As of now I am able to enlarge the textbox to the size of the div but now I need to enlarge the text within it.

Any help will be greatly appreaciated!

This is what I have:
http://jsfiddle.net/gmrcn/2/

Here is my code:

```
  $(function () {

     $('.demo')

    .draggable()

    .resizable();

    });
```

This is design code:

```
<div class="demo">

        <textarea name="TextBox1" rows="2" cols="20" id="TextBox1"></textarea>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #TextBox1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.demo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #ff8811;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 300px;
}

#content
{
    padding-bottom: 3em;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could hook into the resize event of the resizable method, for example:

```
$(function () {

     $('.demo')
    .draggable()
    .resizable({
        resize: function(event, ui) {
           $('#TextBox1').css('font-size', $(this).height() / 3);
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: Great! but one thing as its extending and its height is remain the same.How do I increase it's height as well?

Comment: @user944919 - the code i've shown is really only for demo purposes. How you decide to resize your font is really up to you and your requirements. You can use `$(this).height()` and `$(this).width()` to get the size of your div and using those dimensions decide on the size of your font. TBH, this is the difficult part.